# Magento product page is a mess

Tags: magento-1.9

On my magento product page I am having an issue which is quite strange I am not able to see additional details and tab data as I am seeing an array of values instead of data.

Upper portion is perfect that is I can view product-image,details, add to cart button etc but lower portion is all messed up.

Could you please direct me to resolve this issue?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvraV.jpg

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot a `print_r` or `var_dump` somewhere in a block or template. Most probably in something related to the reviews.
You can enable the [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) and you should see the template or block with the problem.